# Floats lost error with figure and tcolorbox

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

For some reason, whenever I try to insert a figure into this tcolorbox, I run into this error: `Float(s) lost.`.

I've seen examples of tcolorboxes supporting figures, so I'm wondering if it has to do with tcbtheorem or tcblisting (the box I'm currently using), or if it's something with the tcolorbox settings I've just not set up right.

Here is the code for the tcolorboxes in question:

```
% listings box
\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbcodex}[2][]{%
        colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
        segmentation style={solid, draw=gray!20, line width=1pt},
        comment and listing,
        title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
        comment={#2},#1
}

% theorem box
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, list inside=definitionlist]{tcbdefinition}{Definition}{%
        colback=red!5, colbacktitle=red!20, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false
}{def}
```

And here is the code for both boxes I have before compiling and error:

```
% example box
\begin{tcbexample}[name = Test Example, listing options = {language = Python}]
{Here is a comment.
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{foo.png}
\centering\caption{Here is a caption.}
\end{figure}
And there goes my figure.}
Here is some code.
\end{tcbexample}

% definition theorem box
\begin{definition}[Definition]
Here I will place a figure.
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{foo.png}
\centering\caption{Here is a caption.}
\end{figure}
And there goes my figure.
\end{definition}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: you can not put a figure in a box, did you intended the other way, putting the box in the figure?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well that does make sense now as to why there's an error. Will using \wrapfigure work? I just saw some examples and they seem to use that.

Comment: if the image is part of the definition then it isn't a float at all and you should just use `\includegraphics` without a surrounding `figure`

Comment: The best solution is to use a minipage or center environment and \captionof{figure}.